# yarn: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, datatables, yarnpkg

For the first time I am using Yarn. I have installed the latest version of Laravel Boilerplate (http://laravel-boilerplate.com/) and there is used Yarn.

My need is to include the JS library DataTables (https://datatables.net/).
Unfortunately I am new to Yarn and I am not sure if I am making everything right, because I get the error:

> [Show/hide message details.] ReferenceError: $ is not defined

which is on the this line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
```

This is telling me that it cannot find the jquery library, but it should be there.

Here is the webpack.mix.js code:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.setPublicPath('public');

mix.sass('resources/sass/frontend/app.scss', 'css/frontend/frontend.css')
    .sass('resources/sass/backend/app.scss', 'css/backend/backend.css')
    .js('resources/js/frontend/app.js', 'js/frontend/frontend.js')
    .js([
        'resources/js/backend/before.js',
        'resources/js/backend/app.js',
        'resources/js/backend/after.js'
    ], 'js/backend/backend.js')
    .extract([
        'jquery',
        'datatables.net-dt',
        'bootstrap',
        'popper.js/dist/umd/popper',
        'axios',
        'sweetalert2',
        'lodash',
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core',
        '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons',
        '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons',
        '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
    ]);

if (mix.inProduction() || process.env.npm_lifecycle_event !== 'hot') {
    mix.version();
}
```

Every time I call the command "yarn prod" in order to create the CSS and js files, but the DataTables are not working.

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because of `yarn`. Yarn is a package manager, it doesn't run any part of your application's code so cannot generate an error like yours. Yarn is just for downloading packages and manage their dependencies.

Then comes `Laravel Mix` for you, which is just a wrapper around `Webpack`. Webpack reads your application code, handles your `require` and `import` commands in your `.js` files and then generates your bundles.

**How to make it work:**

I suppose you did run the `yarn` command (without params) in your project root once when you installed Laravel Boilerplate. There should be a lot of packages inside your `node_modules` directory (more than 900).

Then you did run `yarn add -D datatables.net-dt` also. Now you should have a `datatables.net` and a `datatables.net-dt` folder inside `node_modules`.

I see you've added `datatables.net-dt` in your `webpack.mix.js`, this is OK! You **don't** need any other `require( 'datatables.net-dt' )( window, $ );` as said in the documentation. That one line in your `webpack.mix.js` is enough! `DataTable` will be inside your `vendor.js`.

Now create an [example table](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) with attribute `id="example"` in your `index.blade.php` then add this code to the bottom of your `resources\js\frontend\app.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

Then run `yarn dev` to let Webpack generate your bundles (compiled js files) and view your site in the browser. Following these, it should be working on a fresh install install of Laravel Boilerplate, without any error. I've just tested id now, works like charm.

**Your possible bug:**

`$ is not defined` tells that some part of your code is trying to use `jQuery` before it has been loaded.

It's important that you must write your codes using `jQuery` (shortened `$`) inside your `resources\js\frontend\app.js` or in a separate `.js` which is later required/imported into this file! It's because `jQuery` and other vendor packages like `DataTable` are stored in `vendor.js`, which must be loaded before any calls to them.

So **don't use** custom `<script>` tags in your `html`'s `<head>` tag for your app code because that will be loaded and executed before any other defined in the bottom of your `<body>` tag!

Have a look at this file `resources\views\frontend\layouts\app.blade.php`. In the bottom of the `body` tag you'll see this:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
@stack('before-scripts')
{!! script(mix('js/manifest.js')) !!}
{!! script(mix('js/vendor.js')) !!}
{!! script(mix('js/frontend.js')) !!}
@stack('after-scripts')
```

Your `resources\js\frontend\app.js` and all its imported scripts will be compiled to this `js/frontend.js` file.

**How jQuery is imported in Laravel Boilerplate:**

This is done well by default, you don't have to bother with it. Open your `resources\js\bootstrap.js` and see these two lines:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

This file will then imported by `frontend/app.js`. So write your code here and you'll be fine...

---

*PS.: If this doesn't helps you to make it work, you should edit your question and provide more info on your sources. A screenshot for example taken from your Chrome DevTools, showing the lines of your JavaScript where the error occurred.*

Comment: thank you @ARS81 I am not sure what was the reason for getting that error, I think everything I have done as you described. The important thing is that now i have checked everything step by step and now is perfect. Many thanks again !

Comment: i have one question. I have added also the bootstrap-datepicker package to my backend.css, unfortunately i dont see the styles. I have included one datepicker.css right after my backend.css code, but it doesnt change anything. How should i include some js package css ? Should i mix it, if yes - how is the best practice ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @VinceCarter Are you sure you want it in your backend/admin UI in your app? Anyway... You shouldn't use an extra `<link>` tag in your `html` to include the css of this new package. Rather than open up your `resources\sass\backend\app.scss` file and add this line to the end `@import '~bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css';` Or in `frontend\app.scss` (?) Of course you have it installed like `yarn add -D bootstrap-datepicker` and `bootstrap-datepicker` added in your `webpack.mix.js` like you did it before with `datatables.net-dt` package. Tested and worked well for me.

Comment: @VinceCarter of course you have to run `npm run dev` after doing this to re-generate your compiled `js` and `css` files...

Comment: thanks again. i have imported the datepicker.css file into to the backend/app.scss and the magic happens :)

Comment: I have one last question. In the webpack.mix.js there are around 10 includes in the extract() part. But in my node_modules, there are more than 1000 folders. Why is that ? is it possible somehow to remove the unneeded folders ?

Comment: No. They are needed dependencies. That's how npm works... You use 10 packages but they depends on hundreds of other opensource packages. So never delete or modify anything inside node_modules!

Comment: I appreciate your help !